# How do I find a Property in a %DIctionary.ClassDefinition by property Name?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I have the following line of code in a class:

```
 Set objDClass = ##class(%Dictionary.ClassDefinition).%OpenId("Dict.ProcCde")
```

this creates an object reference to the class definition of another class.  The Dict.ProcCde class has 173 properties defined.  I would like to be able to retrieve an object reference to a specific property by it's property name (which I believe is it's Id)  but I'm not sure how to do it short of creating a loop to go through objDClass.Properies one at a time and look for the right property name. When I type in objDClass.Properties. in cache studio I see a number of methods that look like they may work but I can't find any documentation on them or make them work.  Specifically, objDClass.Properties.FindObjectId(PropertyName) looked like it would do the trick but doesn't.  Other methods that may are: FindExistingObjectId, FindObject but none work.  Does anyone know of way to retrieve a %Dictionary.PropertyDefinition object from a %Dictionary.ClassDefinition object by it's property name?  Can anyone point me to documentation for the .Properties methods mentioned above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s prop=##class(%Dictionary.PropertyDefinition).%OpenId("Dict.ProcCde||SomeProperty")
or
s prop=##class(%PropertyDefinition).%OpenId("Dict.ProcCde:SomeProperty")

Comment: [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_classdef#GOBJ_C220)

Comment: Thanks, I should of thought of this myself!